# What is the probability $P(X>0\mid X+Y>0)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are both independent normal mean zero with different variances?

Tags: probability, integration, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, bivariate-distributions

Let $X$ have standard deviation $\sigma$ and $Y$ standard deviation $\tau$. 
I can write
$$P(X>0\mid X+Y>0) = \frac{P(X>0, X+Y>0)}{P(X+Y>0)}$$
As all variables are zero-mean and symmetric, $P(X+Y>0)=1/2$, so that
$$P(X>0\mid X+Y>0) = 2 P(X>0, X+Y>0) = 2 P(X>0, Y>-X)$$
Using the independence of $X$ and $Y$ and the notation $\Phi$ and $\phi$ for the standard normals, I get
$$P(X>0\mid X+Y>0) = 2 \int_0^\infty \phi\left(\frac{x}{\sigma}\right)
\left(1-\Phi\left(-\frac{x}{\tau}\right)\right) dx.$$
But from here on I do not know how to continue to get a simple expression. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: It might help to draw the picture in 2 dimensions.  Draw the line $x+y=0$ and look at symmetry to tell you what "fraction" of the region $x+y >0$ has $x>0$.

Comment: @Ian, the upper half of the 4th quadrant still has $x>0$.  The answer is actually $3/4$.